# Genesis block without chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger

My intention is to replicate the [Marbles application](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles), a Hyperledger demo. Using instructions from [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md), I was able to set-up a Blockchain network on my Ubuntu VM. However, I hadn't deployed the chaincode. When I invoked the API to read the chain, I got one block; which, I think, is the genesis block. There was some log listing also about the same.

My question is as follows. If my intent to run a blockchain is to launch a distributed application (e.g. Marbles), then, without the chaincode deployed, why is a genesis block mined? With no chaincode deployed, the blockchain network cannot process any transactions, therefore, no transactions could (should) exist in the block.

So, why does a genesis block get mined without the chaincode deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, genesis block is created as very first block in the ledger automatically by Validation Peers. 
It does not contain any transactions included and has unique format. An example is:

```
{"nonHashData":{"localLedgerCommitTimestamp":{"seconds":1469225503,"nanos":346624842}}}
```

As you can see it has no “previousBlockHash” property in it. You can customise this block's content in core.yaml file using `ledger.blockchain.genesisBlock`:

```
ledger:

  blockchain:

    # Define the genesis block
    genesisBlock:

      # Deploy chaincodes into the genesis block
      chaincode:
          path: github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/example/chaincode/chaincode_example01
          type: GOLANG
          constructor:
            func: init
            args:
              - alice
              - "4"
              - bob
              - "10"
```

Comment: Thanks. What scenarios, do you think, will benefit from a setting that says, genesis block should have at least one transaction (that seeds the genesis block)?

Comment: First transaction can be “Deploy” only (The answer updated with example). We just have a choice if we would like to deploy something at first start, or do that later manually.